# Admin grid massaction checkboxes default checked & option set to action I want

Tags: adminhtml, grid, default, massaction, checkbox

Just like the question [keep the checkboxes of mass action checked for some items, by default](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/keep-the-checkboxes-of-mass-action-checked-for-some-items-by-default), but I simply want all checkboxes checked by default, plus a default mass-action is selected on first landing.

E.g. a landing grid page:
[image: Screenshot]

Should I just use JS to select them? Or need to go through all backend PHP for it?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a selected mass action by default by defining it in your grid block like this:

```
   $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('mass_action_code_here', array(
        'label'    => Mage::helper('helper_name_here')->__('Label here'),
        'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/urlHere'),
        'selected' => true, //This is what you need
    ));
```

And you can select all the checkboxes by default like this.

Add a method called `_prepareMassactionColumn` in your grid block with this content.

```
protected function _prepareMassactionColumn()
{
    parent::_prepareMassactionColumn();
    $ids = Mage::getModel('your_model/alias_here')->getCollection()->getAllIds();
    $this->getColumn('massaction')->setValues($ids);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: not working on magento 2.3

Comment: @ManishMaheshwari Of course it doesn't. The question and answer are for magento 1.